# Why my tomcat jsvc process sleeps and halts there after a while running

Tags: linux, tomcat6

I has installed my tomcat version 6 on centos 5.5 using jsvc as the daemon process. After some hours or some days running, the tomcat jsvc process is sleeping there and uses %100 of the CPU resources, which is shown in the top command output screen. The following is the detail of the output screen.

```
PID  USER PR NI VIRT  RES SHR S %CPU  %MEM COMMAND    
8670 root 18  0 33.3g 32g 10m S 100.0 51.5 jsvc
```

I has set the jvm max memory value to 32G while the server box has 64G memory, so don't surprise on the VIRT value. As you can see on the output message, the process status is S which means sleep. Here is my guess, the jvm uses too many memory, so jvm need a long time to do the GC operation, that is why jsvc use %100 of cpu resources.

So is there anyone else has encountered the problem before. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out that there is a dead loop happens in the program, which eats all the memory and cpu resources.

So this question can be close now.